Prove that you can't form arbitrary incontiguous subsequence from a sequence but only contiguous
I have this discrete math problem that comes from a programming problem. The problem states:

Given a sequence $T$ of values: $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$. You can do this operation as
many times as you want:

Take an $i$ index where the appended(or original) array of size $m(m \geq n)$
Append this value $a_i * ... * a_m$ to T

Prove that you can only form contiguous series of $*$ operators on the original array everytime applying this operation
but not incontiguous one(for instance, $a_3 * a_4 * ... * a_n$ but
not $a_2 * a_4 * a_6 * ...$)

where $*$ is some operator that satisfy the condition:  $X * X = 0$ such as the logical XOR.
I can only prove the first part. To form contiguous sequence $a_i,...,a_j(i<j)$ out of the original array of size $n$ by:
$a_1, ... a_n$ becomes
$a_1, ..., a_n, (a_{j + 1}* ...*a_n)$ becomes
$a_1, ..., a_n, (a_{j + 1}* ...*a_n), (a_i *...*a_j)$
It's great if I have a hint on this. It seems impossible to form incontiguous one
It may reduce to this simple problem(we prove the whole problem using induction):

You can't form $a_1 \oplus a_3$ from $a_1, a_2, a_3$.


I am assuming the OP means "contiguous" though I still don't know what the definition of a contiguous sequence is.

Thanks. I did manage to clarify more. What I mean is if the original is $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$. You can't form something like $a_2 * a_4 * a_6, ...$ by using the operation, which is incontiguous.

Can you rephrase item 1 into something sensible?

I am guessing from your use of $\oplus$ at the end, that you are assuming that $$ is both commutitive and associative, and that $0$ is an identity element for it. But you did not specify any of this in the problem statement, even though it appears to be vital to your question. Normally $$ as an operator denotes a multiplication, which is not always commutative, and for which $0$ is an annihilator, not an identity.
